# How do you sort a generic list in C# and allow NULL items to appear first in the list?

Tags: c#, generics, comparison

I have a generic list of objects in C#, for example sake, here's what the object might be.

```
public class Thing {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime EditDate { get; set; }
}

var things = new List<Thing>();
```

Now I want to call:

```
thing.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.EditDate.CompareTo(t2.EditDate));
```

However, some of my EditDate properties are null.  I want these objects with a null EditDate property to show up at the top of my list (i.e. closer to the zero index).  How can I do this?

Comment: In your given example, you're using DateTime type, which cannot be null. Can you clarify the example or the question?

Comment: The title is a bit misleading, the question is about comparison, and only indirectly about sorting. You might want to edit it to make that clear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a somewhat more complex lambda, such as:

```
things.Sort((t1, t2) => 
{
 if (t1 == null)
 {
   return (t2 == null) ? 0 : -1;
 }
 if (t2 == null)
 {
   return 1;
 }
 return t1.EditDate.CompareTo(t2.EditDate);
});
```

`EndDate` cannot be `null` as it is a value type. However, if you had a specific value of `EndDate` that you consider as `null`, you could modify the above code to take that into account in a similar fashion to how I've coped with `t1` or `t2` being `null`.

Comment: You should switch == to Object.Reference equals.  You're looking for object identity but asking for object equality.  These are sadly two different items with only one construct in C#

Comment: For this example your code works.  But in a more abstract sample, it's possible for someone to overload == to not be reference identity (strings for instance).  In that case null can be intepreted differently and give interesting results.

Answer (score 2):

Have Thing implement IComparable such that Things with null editDates have a higher order than those with an edit date. Then modify the sort expression to sort on the objects and not the edit dates.

Answer (score 0):

List has a [sort function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) that takes a delegate.

Now that I've read the question

```
TheList.Sort(int delegate(Type a, Type b)
{
    if (a.memeber == null) return -1;
    if (b.memeber == null) return 1;
    if (a.memeber<b.memeber) return -1;
    if (b.memeber<a.memeber) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from ffpf should work.

But if you have some time read through this great post about sorting with nulls from the BCL team 


http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/10/06/the-compare-contract-kim-hamilton.aspx